# Ultragrid Export Sort Order / Indicator

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

To make a long story short, we have a legacy application which displays an infragistics grid where users can export the grid display. The issue I'm having is that there's a particular order in which they want the export to occur, and if I set the order within the grid view prior to export, it retains this order, however if I try to force it "on export", it doesn't seem to work despite trying to set it.   Here's my code (VB), as you can see just prior to import I try to set the "sortindicator", but I suspect I'm missing something.

```
            Dim FileName As String
            Dim I As Integer
            I = 1

            FileName = "C:\ReconciliationReport.xls"

            While System.IO.File.Exists(FileName)
                FileName = "C:\ReconciliationReport_" & I & ".xls"
                I = I + 1
            End While

            grdReconciliationReport.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ReconciliationOrder").SortIndicator = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.SortIndicator.Ascending


            UltraGridExcelExporter.Export(grdReconciliationReport, FileName)
```

Answer (score 2):

During the export of the grid UltraGridExcelExporter creates its own copy of the Layout. This is done exactly to allow you to sort, hide, delete and any other action in the layout without changing the actual grid. To sort the grid by any column you need to handle ExportStarted event. The event argument contains reference to the clonned layout. You can use code like this:

```
Private Sub UltraGridExcelExporter_ExportStarted(sender As Object, e As ExcelExport.ExportStartedEventArgs) Handles UltraGridExcelExporter1.ExportStarted
    Dim sortedCol As UltraGridColumn = e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns(1)
    e.Layout.Bands(0).SortedColumns.Add(sortedCol, False, False)
End Sub
```